# Redirect stderr and stdout to one file and stderr to another using cmd

Tags: cmd, io-redirection

I want to start a program and redirect stdout and stderr in one file and stderr to another. I read a lot about using tee but this seems not to work for cmd.

This already works but I need stderr in a second file as well.

```
programm >> combined.log 2>&1
```

I have tried sth like this but it didnt work.

```
program >> combined.log 2>&1 2>> error.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be nice to have your cake and eat it too. That is not always possible. The stderr log can be captured, then appended to the combined log.

```
program >>combined.log 2>err.log
type err.log >>combined.log
```